# Crossing of two concave functions

Tags: calculus

Sorry if this is a bit trivial, but I wonder if someone could help me understand, intuitively, why the following two curves cross:

[Two concave curves crossing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTpR7.png)

I undertand that initially one has a steeper slope, but the rate of decline of that slope is also more important. I don't think that's enough though to be able to say that the two curves cross.

Any intuition would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: to be more specific, I would also like to understand what affects how fast the two curves will cross. That is, when will we have $x^*$ relatively small?

Comment: Clearly they cross, from the picture. Given that the only definition of these curves that you've provided is a picture, there's not much more that can be said on the topic. Is there a more detailed question that you'd like to ask?

Comment: It's useful to consider a new function $d(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ and study when $d(x)=0$, as weel as the first and second derivatives.

Comment: To @TheoBendit, not really. I would basically like to study the slopes and second derivative of each function and then say "ah, because of this and that parameter, we can understand why the two curves cross".

Comment: @MattiP., thanks I will do a trusty table of variations.

Comment: @MattiP., thanks. I did a table of variation and from it I can conclude that f-g is first increasing and then decresing. So in the end I must show that the limit of f-g as x goes to infinity is negative. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: @coreyman317, if f was always steeper than g then they would not cross. So the crossing results in the properties of the slopes and how those slopes change, doesn't it?

Comment: @TheoBendit, actually thinking about it, I do have a more detailed question. What determines how fast those curves cross, ie the location of $x^*$. I would like to understand the cases for which $x^*$ is suffiently small. I'll edit my post to mention that.

Comment: @coreyman317, I need both functions to be 0 at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to consider two smooth functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$, and knowing their derivatives you want to determine whether there exist $x^* >0$ such that $f(x^*)=g(x^*)$.

You have $f(x^*) = f(0) + \int_0^{x^*} f'(x) dx$, and analogously for $g$, sothe condition $f(x^*)=g(x^*)$ translates to
$$ \int_0^{x^*} f'(x) dx = \int_0^{x^*} g'(x) dx$$
or 
$$ \int_0^{x^*} \big(f'(x)-g'(x)\big) dx = 0 $$
That is a necessary and suffcicient condition, but from it we can infer some simpler necessary (but not sufficient) conditions.

For example, if $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x>0$ or $f'(x)<g'(x)$, then this condition cannot be satisfied. That means that unless $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x>0$, it's necessary that there were regions in which $f'(x)\ge g'(x)$ and regions in which $f'(x) \le g'(x)$. it is a necessary condition, but not sufficient.

If $f'(0)>g'(0)$ then you can deduce that at the first point of interesction (if it exists) you'd have $f'(x^*)\le g'(x^*)$. That is because if we had $f'(x^*) > g'(x^*)$ there would exist $\delta >0$ such that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for $x\in[x^*-\delta,x^*]$. Since, by assumption $x^*$ is the first interesction, it would mean that $f(x^*-\delta) > g(x^*-\delta)$. We have then
$$ 0 = f(x^*)-g(x^*) = f(x^*-\delta) - g(x^*-\delta) + \int_{x^*-\delta}^{x^*} \big(f'(x)-g'(x)\big) dx > 0 $$
which is a contradiction.

There are more conditions that can be deduced, but whether they are useful or not depends on the specific case.

If you expand $f$ and $g$ in Taylor series, you have $$f(x) = f'(0) x + \frac12 f''(0)x^2 + O(x^3)$$
$$g(x) = g'(0) x + \frac12 g''(0)x^2 + O(x^3)$$
Assuming that the first interesction $x^*$ happens in the region where the first two terms are a good approximation fo $f$ and $g$, you have
$$ f'(0) x^* + \frac12 f''(0)(x^*)^2 \approx g'(0) x^* + \frac12 g''(0)(x^*)^2$$
which gives you $$ x^* \approx 2\frac{f'(0)-g'(0)}{g''(0)-f''(0)}$$
If the right side gives you a negative number, or a number outside the region where you can approximate $f$ and $g$ with only two terms of the Taylor series, then you cannot use this approximation. You can then try the approximation with more terms, or expansion around a different point to get a different approximation for $x^*$.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful to help structure my thoughts around the problem, especially given that my question is relatively vague.

Comment: What if I had something more specific, say $f(x) = x / (a + b x)$ and $g(x) = x / (\alpha + \beta x)$, where $a < \alpha$ and $b > \beta$?

Comment: Assuming all these parameters are positive, the graphs will always interect, which follows from the facts that $$ f'(0) = \frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{\alpha} = g'(0)$$ $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{\beta} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x) $$
$x^*$ can be easily calculated explicitly $$ x^* = \frac{\alpha - a}{b-\beta}$$